# Change Timestamp granularity

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I change the granularity of a timestamp in Oracle?

For example:

```
28.10.2013 15:15:15
```

to

```
28.10.2013 15:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will use the [trunc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) command

Sample data:

```
with dates as ( -- generating sample data
select to_date('10/28/2013 09:08:19', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
select to_date('10/28/2013 09:18:19', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
select to_date('10/28/2013 09:38:19', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
select to_date('10/28/2013 09:48:19', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') from dual)
```

Query to run:

```
select dt,
    trunc(dt,'hh') as new_dt
from dates
```

Results in

```
DT                   new_dt
-------------------- -------------------
2013-10-28 09:08:19  2013-10-28 09:00:00
2013-10-28 09:18:19  2013-10-28 09:00:00
2013-10-28 09:38:19  2013-10-28 09:00:00
2013-10-28 09:48:19  2013-10-28 09:00:00
```

Comment: for some reason this return only the date value

Comment: You can test it by adjusting your date format for the session: `ALTER SESSION     SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';`